# Click event not captured inside child div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I m trying out a list component using basic HTML, css and JQuery. I want the list item to be selected on click event. When i click on the space around the list items's text (`padding space`), click event is captured. But when i click on the text (also the space taken by the entire `file-name div`), click event is not captured. May be because of the child div inside? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```js
function selectFile(id, key) {
  if($(id).hasClass('selected')) {
    $(id).removeClass('selected');
  } else {
    $(id).addClass('selected');
  }
}

$('.file-list-section').on('click', function(event) {
  selectFile('#'+event.target.id, event.target.dataset.key);
})
```

```css
.file-row {
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.file-list-section .file-row.selected {
    background: #26a69a;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<div id="fileList" class="file-list-section">
  <div class="file-row" id="fileId_0" data-key="cd58ef701e28f6df8.jpg">
    <div class="file-name">cd58ef701e28f6df8.jpg</div>
  </div>
  <div class="file-row" id="fileId_1" data-key="a682e06e25c5c86.jpg">
    <div class="file-name">a682e06e25c5c86.jpg</div>
  </div>
  <div class="file-row" id="fileId_2" data-key="Jefree" copy.jpeg="">
    <div class="file-name">Jefree copy.jpeg</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no ID on the file-name - you need to pass the parent ID when clicking on the file-name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function selectFile(id, key) {
  if($(id).hasClass('selected')) {
    $(id).removeClass('selected');
  } else {
    $(id).addClass('selected');
  }
}

$('.file-list-section .file-row').on('click', function(event) {

  selectFile('#'+$(this).attr('id'), $(this).data('key'));
})
```

```css
.file-row {
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.file-list-section .file-row.selected {
    background: #26a69a;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<div id="fileList" class="file-list-section">
  <div class="file-row" id="fileId_0" data-key="cd58ef701e28f6df8.jpg">
    <div class="file-name">cd58ef701e28f6df8.jpg</div>
  </div>
  <div class="file-row" id="fileId_1" data-key="a682e06e25c5c86.jpg">
    <div class="file-name">a682e06e25c5c86.jpg</div>
  </div>
  <div class="file-row" id="fileId_2" data-key="Jefree copy.jpeg">
    <div class="file-name">Jefree copy.jpeg</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code was focused on the class for the entire list instead of handling each list item individually. I've simplified your jQuery to say if I click on "this" .file-row toggle the class Selected. This allows more than one to highlight. If you want only one at a time, clear all 'selected' classes on each click.

```js
$('.file-row').removeClass('selected');

$('.file-row').click(function(){
$(this).toggleClass('selected');
})
```

```css
.file-row {
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.file-list-section .file-row.selected {
    background: #26a69a;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<div id="fileList" class="file-list-section">
  <div class="file-row" id="fileId_0" data-key="cd58ef701e28f6df8.jpg">
    <div class="file-name">cd58ef701e28f6df8.jpg</div>
  </div>
  <div class="file-row" id="fileId_1" data-key="a682e06e25c5c86.jpg">
    <div class="file-name">a682e06e25c5c86.jpg</div>
  </div>
  <div class="file-row" id="fileId_2" data-key="Jefree" copy.jpeg="">
    <div class="file-name">Jefree copy.jpeg</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should target the `file-row` for event binding and use `this` to perform the desired operation.

```js
function selectFile() {
  $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  
  console.clear();
  console.log($(this).data("key"), $(this).find('.file-name').text());
}

$('.file-list-section').on('click', '.file-row', selectFile)
```

```css
.file-row {
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.file-list-section .file-row.selected {
  background: #26a69a;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<div id="fileList" class="file-list-section">
  <div class="file-row" id="fileId_0" data-key="cd58ef701e28f6df8.jpg">
    <div class="file-name">cd58ef701e28f6df8.jpg</div>
  </div>
  <div class="file-row" id="fileId_1" data-key="a682e06e25c5c86.jpg">
    <div class="file-name">a682e06e25c5c86.jpg</div>
  </div>
  <div class="file-row" id="fileId_2" data-key="Jefree" copy.jpeg="">
    <div class="file-name">Jefree copy.jpeg</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your script with following..

```js
function selectFile(id, key) {
  if($(id).hasClass('selected')) {
    $(id).removeClass('selected');
  } else {
    $(id).addClass('selected');
  }
}

$('.file-list-section .file-row').on('click', function(event) {
  selectFile('#'+$(this).attr('id'), $(this).data('key'));
})
```

```css
.file-row {
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.file-list-section .file-row.selected {
    background: #26a69a;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<div id="fileList" class="file-list-section">
  <div class="file-row" id="fileId_0" data-key="cd58ef701e28f6df8.jpg">
    <div class="file-name">cd58ef701e28f6df8.jpg</div>
  </div>
  <div class="file-row" id="fileId_1" data-key="a682e06e25c5c86.jpg">
    <div class="file-name">a682e06e25c5c86.jpg</div>
  </div>
  <div class="file-row" id="fileId_2" data-key="Jefree" copy.jpeg="">
    <div class="file-name">Jefree copy.jpeg</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are too narrow in your passing of event - instead add the event handler to the div with the key

Also toggle the class instead of testing the class:

```js
$('.file-row').on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  console.log($(this).data("key"))
});
```

```css
.file-row {
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.file-list-section .file-row.selected {
    background: #26a69a;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<div id="fileList" class="file-list-section">
  <div class="file-row" id="fileId_0" data-key="cd58ef701e28f6df8.jpg">
    <div class="file-name">cd58ef701e28f6df8.jpg</div>
  </div>
  <div class="file-row" id="fileId_1" data-key="a682e06e25c5c86.jpg">
    <div class="file-name">a682e06e25c5c86.jpg</div>
  </div>
  <div class="file-row" id="fileId_2" data-key="Jefree" copy.jpeg="">
    <div class="file-name">Jefree copy.jpeg</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Passing element would be more efficient then a selector created using `'#'+$(this).attr("id")`

Comment: Actually not passing anything but just assign the code directly to the class is the simplest.

Comment: Now your answer is equivalent to mine :)

Comment: Ah, I see. You do go through one more step than I